# Chat server design (end-to end encryption)

Tags: java, spring, encryption

Good day!

I have several questions about chat server design - maybe someone will point me to right direction. 
I have some experience in cryptography and client-side programming in c++ and java, but zero experience in server-side.

First of all, my goal is simple end-to end encryption chat with encrypted messages stored on the server. It is not something commercial, just my training.

As I see it  - it is something like spring web-socket -> spring mvc -> signal protocol (or more simple xmpp) -> database (something like RethinkDB with subscribing). 
And I just dunno where and how to start. What parts should be implemented first?

I think ill do all in this way -

1) Simple server with many web-socket connections.

2) Add some king of registration with saving to DB.

3) Add encryption to web socket

4) Create some kind of messages (plane strings) transfer from client to client( how ??? )

5) Add messages protocol (xmpp or signal )

So any ideas- advises?

Comment: This question is far too broad for SO.

Comment: You suggest me to close this question and to go find answer somewhere else?

Comment: @RedCollarPanda : I always **only** used socket, you can send strings to IPs, and its fairly easy, the encryption is the harder part.